# Maven jar dependencies in Gradle not appearing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have a private Maven repo for a jar file with some Java libraries, which I hope to use in an Android project. My Gradle file looks something like this (details removed for anonymity)

```
maven {
    url "s3://location/release"
    credentials(AwsCredentials) {
        accessKey "accessKey"
        secretKey "secretKey"
    }
}
```

in my repositories, and then

```
compile 'com.github.name.group:project:version'
```

in my dependencies. Gradle build compiles perfectly, and the dependency shows up when I check in module settings.

However, typing

```
import com.github
```

in a java file will immediately cause Android Studio to complain that it cannot resolve this.

I basically just want to add the Maven jar as a library, so I can use the classes and methods inside, without having to copy the jar file to my directory, since the library in question is being updated frequently.

Comment: Have you let Android Studio manage the gradle project and automatically import the build.gradle? Do the dependencies appear in the Gradle tool window? What about external dependencies in the project view? Can you see it there and expand it and see the classes you need? Why are you typing the import statement anyway? Android Studio will auto-import for you. Or is it just for the SO question?

Comment: Just start typing the class name you want to use, Android Studio will show suggestion which package needs to be imported.

Comment: external dependencies don't appear